# Can anyone point out what mistake I made in my code?

Tags: c

> Pooja would like to withdraw X $US from an ATM. The cash machine will
> only accept the transaction if X is a multiple of 5, and Pooja's
> account balance has enough cash to perform the withdrawal transaction
> (including bank charges). For each successful withdrawal the bank
> charges 0.50 $US. Calculate Pooja's account balance after an attempted
> transaction.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float initialamt;
    int deductamt =0;
// taking input of the account balance and money to be withdrawn 
    scanf("%f", &initialamt);
    scanf("%d", &deductamt);
// Checking if the mat is a multiple of 5 and less than act balance
    if(deductamt%5 ==0 && deductamt<= initialamt-0.50)
    {
        initialamt = initialamt - deductamt -0.50;
        printf("%2f", initialamt);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%2f", initialamt);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What exactly is your problem with that code? What input do you provide, what output do you expect and what wrong output do you get instead?

Comment: The input is the account balance and money they wish to withdraw. 
The code is running fine on my laptop but when I upload it on CodeChef its showing wrong answer.

Comment: In addition to the input order you're also not outputting the answer to two decimal places. That's `%.2f` with the decimal point.

Comment: 'float initialamt;' that's your first mistake when dealing with currency.

Comment: For future questions, please do not describe input. Show it. Add exact input and output to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the question on CodeChef, is your question https://www.codechef.com/problems/HS08TEST?

Then what the question input is deduct - init balance in order, but not init balance - deduct in order, so just switch the scanf.

```
scanf("%d", &deductamt);
scanf("%f", &initialamt);
```